# SPLIT QUERY results into separate rows when one column's data contains CSV

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

In this `QUERY`

```excel
=QUERY(QUERY(Estimate!A2:Y,"SELECT A,D,E,F,G,H,J,Y",0)
```

Column Y contains a CSV list.  How can I split this up into multiple rows in the results?

I tried this, without success:

```excel
=QUERY(QUERY(Estimate!A2:Y,"SELECT A,D,E,F,G,H,J,'"&SPLIT(Estimate!Y2,", ",TRUE,TRUE)&"'",0),"OFFSET 1",0)
```

[My sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-FdpxsNcrqXXWroYzeAQZz5TuyEX6xKnTif0rrrJl60/edit#gid=536517447&range=A2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 SUBSTITUTE(A2:C, " ", "♦"), "select Col1,Col2,Col3", 0)),, 999^99)), " ,"), "♦", " ")))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(C2:C, ","))<>"", "♦"&A2:A&"♠"&B2:B&"♠"&SPLIT(C2:C, ","), ))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♦")), "♠")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you! But can the results of the split be listed (transposed) vertically in new rows instead of new columns though?

Comment: Works great!  However, if any of the source columns are blank, they are omitted from the results.  :-(

Comment: @Trey you mean like C5?

Comment: No, it would be more like if B4 were blank. But I’ve modified your formula to include an additional 5 or 6 columns before the CSV column (same sheet I’ve been messing with all week).

Comment: An alternative, which may actually be the best long term solution, would be to join `Estimate!D2:D` and `Estimate!E2:E`.  When I try to just add that in though, it goes haywire.

Comment: My solution for now: `=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(Estimate!Y2:Y, ","))<>"", "♦"&Estimate!A2:A&"♠"&Estimate!D2:D&"♠"&IF(Estimate!E2:E<>"",Estimate!E2:E," ")&"♠"&Estimate!F2:F&"♠"&Estimate!G2:G&"♠"&Estimate!H2:H&"♠"&Estimate!J2:J&"♠"&SPLIT(Estimate!Y2:Y, ","), ))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♦")), "♠")))`